# How do you use React-bootstrap with Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I have started using Typescript in my project next to React-Bootstrap and the following piece of code:

```
 const renderSearchAddressButton = (): JSX.Element => {
    return (
      <div className="search-address-button">
        <Button variant="myownvariant" onClick={onClickSearchAddressButton}>
          {t('search-address-button')}
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  };
```

Gives me a Lint error because myownvariant is not a correct variant. The code works but the only variant types allowed are the following:

```
variant?:
    | 'primary'
    | 'secondary'
    | 'success'
    | 'danger'
    | 'warning'
    | 'info'
    | 'dark'
    | 'light'
    | 'link'
    | 'outline-primary'
    | 'outline-secondary'
    | 'outline-success'
    | 'outline-danger'
    | 'outline-warning'
    | 'outline-info'
    | 'outline-dark'
    | 'outline-light';
```

Those types are coming from @types/react-bootstrap, but they do not seem aligned to the official react-bootstrap as they do not leave any room for your own variant.

Therefore, the question is, how can I get rid of that error? Is there another package with better types? I thought about modifying the types myself but every time I update my libraries I guess it will get overwritten.

Thank you in advance and regards.

Answer (score 0):

React Bootstrap's Button `variant` parameter supports only the mentioned values. Custom values like `myownvariant` are not allowed. So the typing in `@types/react-bootstrap` is correct.

You can use `bsPrefix` parameter to overwrite existing styles.

```
<Button bsPrefix="myownvariant">Text<Button/>
```

[Button source code](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/v1.0.0/src/Button.js)

Comment: Thanks Nikolai. I have used bsPrefix rather than variant but it does not work. The Button does not have my variant style if I use bsPrefix.

Comment: @JavierGuzman, if you use `bsPrefix` it will add a custom class that you specified. For this CSS class you can add styles. Share you code, CSS and how it's rendered in HTML in a browser.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. At the end, latest React-bootstrap has types included. Still it will not work but I have redefined the Button myself because I am not sure bsPrefix would be the clean way forward. Apparently. there are discussions on going in the official Github about how to allow more flexibility in the types.